# Terraform S3 multiple unknown number of lifecycle rules

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I would like to create a s3 module that allows to attach any number of lifecycle rules. For instance, when you use the module, you should be able to specify something along those lines:

```
"lifecycle_rules": [
   "prefix", "enabled", "expiration",
   "prefix", "enabled", "expiration"
]
```

then parse that data into 2 separate lifecycle rules. However, I noticed that lifecycle_rule for s3 resource does not support count variable so I am stuck on how to proceed. Any suggestions?